# Why the object is initialized at 0 as the default value in c #

Tags: c#, asp.net

I writes a code in c#.
using Entities...
all my Entities Object initialized at zero at their Primary Key field.
why does it happens?
and how I should uninitialized them?
I want them to get theirs id's in SQL...
here is my object:

```
    public partial class Aircraft
    {
        public Aircraft()
        {
            Criterion = new HashSet<Criterion>();
            Flight = new HashSet<Flight>();
        }

        public int AircraftId { get; set; }
        public string AircraftName { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ProductionYear { get; set; }
        public int? FirstRow { get; set; }
        public int? LastRow { get; set; }
        public string SeatsMapUrl { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Criterion> Criterion { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Flight> Flight { get; set; }
    }
```

I create instance of it:

```
Aircraft aircraft = new Aircraft();
```

and while debugging this code
I found that the field - aircraftId (the Primary Key in SQL) - initialized at zero??
what should I to fix it?

Comment: it seems that your primary key is not set to autoincrement. Can you show us the column declaration of the table?

Comment: Do you get Key Constraint - Violations, then? I share Mong Zhu's suspicion the Primary Key is not set up correctly in DB.

Comment: the primary key is set to autoincrement.

Answer (score 0):

[Default value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values) for `int` is `0`. Integers are [value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types). If you need null as default value for `AircraftId` then you should change type to `int?`.

If auto generated value needed, then usually passing `null` will generate next value (depends on database and their types and/or triggers).